# How to put a link as an parameter in a request?

Tags: java, url, parameters

I'd like to do something like:

http://url.com/page?link=http://otherpage.com/something?action=action&id=6

but of course I can't because it would confuse everything (which ? would it consider as "right" and which &).

Solution? Java tip?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should url encode the variable.

P.s. What do you mean with "java tip"?

Comment: Yes: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html#encode(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)